# Removing Work Item Types from a DevOps Taskboard

Tags: azure-devops, sprint

I have created a copy of the Scrum process for my DevOps project, and created specific work item types (based on the task) for my two project teams(Design and Build). I would like to tailor their specific Sprint taskboards to display only the work item type relevant for their team, which I hope would in turn allow me to tailor the required columns to only those relevant for their work item type.
Can you please advise if this is possible ?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

We can [customize the backlogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-backlogs-boards?view=azure-devops) in the Process of the Organization Settings, and add the required work item types to the corresponding backlog level, but this applies to all teams, I am afraid that the work item type only displayed for a separate team is currently not supported.

We can remove states from columns in **Column Options**:

[image]

[image]

**Update**:

For example: If we want to remove the `test2` column shown in the figure above, we need to map the state to `test2` in the other columns:

[image]

Otherwise we will receive the following prompt:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to me so quickly.  The problem is really with the columns I have to include in each teams taskboard .  The two work item types have a different list of states, and as both item types are included, it is forcing me to include ALL states in my columns. I have ordered the columns in each taskboard so that the ones relevant to that team display first, but is it possible to not include some states please ?

Comment: We can remove state from columns in **Column Options**,please view my update.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me.  I have tried to remove the columns, but I then get an error stating that a state is not mapped to a column.

Comment: Its not a state that I need on the taskboard, but I can't save the column updates without mapping it.  Is there a way around this please ?

Comment: According the test results, we need to map the state to be deleted in the column to remove this state.

Comment: Can you explain further please, I'm not quite sure what I need to do.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I updated my answer to explain further.